# Given an implicitly defined equation, verify another equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Please help me with this one, as I can't seem to finalize the calculus here.

> **Ex:** The equation $$ (y+z) \sin z -y(x+y)=0 $$ defines implicitly the function $$z=z(x,y).$$
>
> Show that:
> $$z \sin{z} \frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}} - y^2 \frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}}=0 $$

I tried calculating it by finding $\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}$ and $\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}}$ directly out of the given equation and replacing it, but I don't think that's correct since I haven't gotten anywhere with my results. Looking forward for some help here.

EDIT: These are the values I found:

$$\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}} = - \frac{F_x}{F_z} = \frac{y}{\sin{z}+(y+z) \cos{z} }$$

$$\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}} = - \frac{F_y}{F_z} = - \frac{\sin{z}-x-2y}{\sin{z}+(y+z) \cos{z} }$$

Comment: Can you edit your question to add what you found for $\partial z/\partial x$ and $\partial z/\partial y$?

Comment: I've added them now @Rahul

Comment: Is my edit ok? There's no need to use $*$ for multiplication, if you absolutely have to use something, please use $ \cdot $, the code is `\cdot`

Comment: @YuriyS Understood, thank you! Now I'm looking forward for someone to actually help me with this exercise. :)

Comment: Your $F_x$ and $F_y$ look fine, but how do you get the $y\sin x$ term in $F_z$? In any case, once you plug them into the equation, almost all of the terms cancel out, but I don't get exactly 0 either. I think there may be an error in the exercise.

Comment: Maybe you want to show $$z \sin{z} \frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}} - y^2 (\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}}-\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}})=0. $$

Comment: @Rahul My mistake. I fixed it now. The $F_z$ term was wrong but now I've edited it. I copied it wrong from my notebook. The problem is still the same. It doesn't add up to 0

Comment: @xpaul Unfortunately, no... That's all that was given for this exercise so I need to prove exactly that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Going from the PDE and applying the method of characteristics leads to the system
$$
\frac{dx}{z\sin z}=\frac{dy}{-y^2}=\frac{dz}{0}
$$
which leads to $z(s)=c_1=const.$ and $x=c_1\sin c_1\dfrac1y+c_2$. Thus the general solution has the form 
$$
0=F(c_1,c_2)=F\left(z,x-\frac{z\sin z}{y}\right).
$$
The original equation can be transformed for $y\ne 0$ to
$$
0=\sin z - \left(x-\frac{z\sin z}{y}\right) -y
$$
where the first two terms are constant along a characteristic curve, while $y$ is not constant, so that the whole expression can not be a solution of the PDE.

This last result also proposes that a fix of the original equation by one letter to 
$$(y+z)\sin z -y(x+z)=0$$ 
would be a solution of the PDE.